# Pay as you go in USA with Three network?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, roaming, mobile-operators, vacations

So I am going to Florida in September.

I would like to be able to take my mobile with me and use it to text people and all the other social networking business. The only problem is EE has ridiculous charges for roaming so I was thinking of buying a 'Three' Pay As You Go SIM which gives unlimited data for 1 month as 'Three' offer no roaming charges in the US.

I use an iPhone 6 on a pay monthly contract with EE, would the method I just explained work for me? (From the UK).

Thanks.

Comment: Probably better asking Three than us.

Comment: If the SIM card fits it ought to work.

Comment: Most likely your phone is locked on EE and you can't use Three or any other SIM card but EE SIMs

Comment: [EE will unlock the phone](https://myaccount.ee.co.uk/device-unlock/) if he's been on the pay monthly plan for six months since buying the phone and doesn't have a balance owing.

Comment: I am on Three, it works automatically abroad.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 6, unusually amongst smartphones, has such a wide variety of radio bands, it can roam, or be used directly, on virtually any network in the US, (or the world!) and [obtain 4G LTE service on any network](https://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/). Which network actually gets used will depend on the SIM you are using and the roaming agreements that that provider has with US carriers.

But the large selection of radio bands does give the option of using a US based SIM card, if you so desire, from almost any carrier (except Verizon may not work or be limited to 4G only).

The only thing you will need to do is to unlock the phone (if it isn't already unlocked). [EE will do this for you](https://myaccount.ee.co.uk/device-unlock/) if you don't have an outstanding balance and also:

> Your device must have been purchased when joining your contract or upgrading and actively used with your pay monthly SIM for a minimum of six months.

There does not appear to be a cost for unlocking the phone.

Once you receive the SMS stating that your phone has been unlocked, you should be able to use any other SIM card in the phone.

Finally, note that with Three, [your data usage in the US comes out of your add-on allowance](http://www.three.co.uk/Support/Roaming_and_international/Mobile_Roaming?content_aid=1214306357859), so you will want to have [one of the add-ons with unlimited data](http://www.three.co.uk/Support/Pay_As_You_Go/Phone_tariffs). You'll also need to [activate roaming](http://www.three.co.uk/Support/Roaming_and_International/Roaming_Settings/Activating_Roaming) on your account.

Comment: The iPhone models are actually geography specific and for example the UK iPhone cannot access every US band. However in practise I have had no problem using mine in most countries I've visited.

Comment: @Calchas No, you can't access _every_ US band, but you can get almost all of them. Enough so that you will get _some_ service on every US carrier.